# Choose which ViewController to switch to by Picker View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uipickerview

I am creating a quiz app, in which the user could select which category they would like to do on the first screen. After they've made their selection the user should press the `begin` button and it will take it to that VC.

*I am not sure if having a view controller for each category would be the most efficient way of going about this. If anyone has any suggestions as far as that goes, they would be very much appreciated.*

So far I have implemented this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
    ObjectiveCViewController *objC;
    CViewController *cVC;
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            objC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ObjectiveCViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:objC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
        case 1:
            cVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:cVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        break;
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly fine as far as switching view controllers goes, but as soon as one is selected it will take the user to that view controller rather than waiting for the button to be pressed.

Also since a button can only be linked to one vc what would be an acceptable solution to this issue also?

Comment: As far as having a new view controller for each category is concerned, it depends on how much different your UI is for each category. If only the questions are different then there is no need to have a different viewcontroller. If you have different ui for each category only then it makes sense. 
As far as picker selection and pressing of button goes.Cedric's answer is correct according to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a viewcontroller for every category is definitely not the way to go. You'll want to make a QuestionViewController which knows how to handle and display Question objects. You can fetch the correct questions based on your selection.

As for what you were doing, this would work:

Have a `UIViewController *viewController` property in your class continuation category to store the selected viewcontroller.

```
- (void)beginButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:self.viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ObjectiveCViewController"];
        break;
        case 1:
            self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cViewController"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you for the help

Comment: As to what you were trying, it is a valid design pattern generally known as 'inheritance' You might make your UIViewController* pointer into some other shared superclass, an abstract superclass of your own design, and implement any shared features there (so that these are declared and known to your other classes)